Markov Chains: Calculating stationary distributions
Let P be the state transition matrix of a Markov chain with $n$ states. The chain has a stationary solution, $\pi$ if $\pi P=\pi$ and $\sum^n_i \pi_i=1$.
I have been told that if the chain is irreducible and aperiodic one can find the stationary distribution by discarding one of the equations in $\pi P=\pi$ and solving the remaining system of $n$ equations in $n$ unknowns. My questions is how can we be sure that the discarded equation is still solved by $\pi$?

The matrix $P$ if it is a transition matrix should normally be square right? Could you provide more context?

I have tried rephrasing it. Hope it has made the question clearer

Hint: Sum the remaining $n-1$ equations. Call it equation (1). Write $1=1$ as equation (2). Now subtract (1) from (2). This will give the equation that was discarded.
